# Entity framework context as static

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

In a web application it would be ok if i declare the context of a entity framework model as static? it would be ok? its not recommended? why?
Thanks!

Comment: damn I'm glad you asked this - I stumbled across it by accident

Answer (score 34):

Almost definitely not.

ObjectContexts get bigger and bigger as more Objects are queried / saved.

Also sharing an ObjectContext between threads, as you would be doing, is not recommended, because of the locking issues and undeterministic side-effects you would have to deal with.

I wrote a tip on this topic a while back.

[Tip 18 - How to decide on a lifetime for your ObjectContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx)

Comment: I was just going to link that post myself

Answer (score 6):

This [answer sort of answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549393/linqtosql-declare-and-instantiate-datacontext-best-practice), so does [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786516/using-a-datacontext-static-variable). I certainly wouldn't consider having it as static!

Rick Strahl has [an in depth article](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/246222.aspx) on the lifecycle management.

Answer (score 2):

I had done this the first time I implemented the entity framework. The problem was that the whole application was getting "completed" events so I had to do a lot of code figuring out where the call came from.

I decided to refactor so each page would have an instance of the context. I like it much better now.

/my experience