# Performance question: EF4.1

Tags: design-patterns, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am using [Repository design pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) "Martin's Fowler" in my application (MVC3, WebForms) also i use "ONLY ONE" DbContext ("Singletone") through out all of my application.

Details:
Repository is looks like that,

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>, IUnitOfWork
```

only one repository wich i create many more repositories, like so:

```
class UserRepository {
   private IRepository<User> _repository;
   //dependency injection via constructor using Ninject 
   public UserRepository(IRepository<User> repository) {
       _repository = repository;
   }
}
```

and so on...

What is best practice in these cases, what you are suggestion to make better???

I have to increase my performance and of course to learn the correct way to do it.

Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using one context for the whole application = you are done. Your application [will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392). You must change it to use a new context instance for each request.

Also I wonder how is your question related to performance and what should your code snippet represent?

Comment: more than one dbcontext throws me an error, something like "you are using more than one dbcontext...." after i changed to use singletone it's worked nicely and didn't failed me once. For the question about performance : It's almost correct if create more than one context this will make performance better? and i've said i need to know how to do it the right way.

Comment: I have already described what you need to do to do it right way. Simply your current solution is terribly wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks that really didn't helped me much.
Any way thank you for the help.

Comment: Here is what i found:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334592/one-dbcontext-per-request-in-asp-net-mvc-without-ioc-container
I think it will tell that your idea is not correct. What is your proff point?

Comment: It tells exactly what I did. It asks how to use a new context per request whereas you are using one context for the whole application (singleton).

Comment: ok can you explane in a simpler language or maybe you can show the code snippet for this please?

Comment: But the question you linked contains both explanations and exampley.