# Understand using in Linq To SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am working with `LINQ To SQL` connection in my `ASP.NET` website but I have some strange problems. I created Singleton entity of `DataContext` for all of the using in the website but I don't really understand why the data not always updated and sometimes adding row to table failed because another entity with the same key already exists (I checked and that is no such entity).

What's the problem and there is another way to use this connection?

```
public class SQLConnection
{
    private LearningDBDataContext dbDataContext;

    public SQLConnection()
    {
        dbDataContext = new LearningDBDataContext();
    }

    public LearningDBDataContext GetDataContextInstance()
    {
        return dbDataContext;
    }

    public void reCreateDBConnection()
    {
        dbDataContext = new LearningDBDataContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create a singleton, the context should be short lived.  You're also not disposing of the context anywhere and thus you are leaking connections.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: so every time that i need information from data-base in need to open new connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely don't use a singleton. If you are using an IoC container then you can set the context to be shortlived - one instance of the context per request. Or in your data access layer, wrap any datacontext instantiations with a `using` statement to be sure that it is properly disposed of, i.e:

```
MyModel model;
using(var context = new LearningDBDataContext()){
     // fetch your data here
     model = ...
}
return model;
```

Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777630/questions-about-entity-framework-context-lifetime) and [this MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx) for more info on this subject.

Comment: Now i have another problem. "Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'." ?

Comment: i created kinf od Model-View-Controller the controller returned list of Teachers table. In the view  i iterate on the list and try to access to teacher.Schedule. (schedule is another related table) then i got this exception.