# EF6 DBContext extension methods, thread safe

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a *DBContext helper class* that uses extension methods:

```
public static class DBContextHelper
{
    public static async Task<T> FindAsync<T>(
        this DBContext context, 
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> match) 
        where T : BaseEntity
    {
        return await context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(match);
    }
}
```

Are extension methods a bad fit for this as they might be accessed by different threads causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

Extensions methods may be thread safe, and may be thread unsafe depending how you write them.

Your method is thread safe while each `DbContext` is accessed from different thread. This is reasonable restriction, cause `DbContext` is not really thread-safe class. (Enabling [Multiple Active Result Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) you can remove this restriction, but it's not good decision cause `DbContext` [tracks data](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx)).

It's good practice to create `DbContext` for a single business operation and immediately *dispose* it — it's the [way of the Unit Of Work pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782804/1051621).

F.e. in Web API scenario you can create different `DbContext` for each HTTP request or even you can create different context for each operation:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User async GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var data = await dbContext.FindAsync((UserData user) => user.Id == id);

            return new User(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The method `FindAsync` works correctly in this code, although it is not convenient to call. I would change the signature:

```
public static class DBSetHelper
{
    public static async Task<T> FindAsync<T>(
        this DbSet<T> set, 
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> match) 
        where T : BaseEntity
    {
        return await set.SingleOrDefaultAsync(match);
    }
}

. . .

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User async GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var data = await dbContext.Users.FindAsync(user => user.Id == id);

            return new User(data);
        }
    }
}
```