# Entity Framework not always get the most update values from the db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

I am having a odd problem with EF caching data, and only getting the values as they were when the DB contect is created.

This is a issue as the DB context is injected on the contractor.

I have set LazyLoadingEnabled to be false.

EF has been set up as database first, this will be something that will be changed so it code first.

I am using autofac for the dependency injection.

I know the following demo is odd, but it is the simplest way to explain it.

So if i call the following code, but if i put a break point on every GetFooById I go into the SQL database and change a value in the foo table, it will not load the new changes it will load the values, as they were before I started.

```
var item1 = _fooService.GetFooById(1);
var item2 = _fooService.GetFooById(1);
var item2 = _fooService.GetFooById(1);
```

I was wondering how to make EF always get the most update values from the db.
My foo service looks like this

```
private readonly DBEntities _dbContext;

    public FooService(DBEntities  dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext= dbContext;
    }

    public Foo GetFooById(int id)
    {
        return  _dbContext.Foo.First(x => x.Id== id);
    }
```

The autofac looks like

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
  .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
  .WithParameter("dbContext", new DBEntities())
  .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: Please show your DI startup code (expecially the part that registers your `DBContext`) and indicate what type of application this is (console, WPF, ASP.NET MVC, etc).

Comment: You'd better redesign your service according https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777630/questions-about-entity-framework-context-lifetime

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `AsNoTracking` method disable Entity Framework caching.

```
public Foo GetFooById(int id)
{
    return  _dbContext.Foo.AsNoTracking().First(x => x.Id== id);
}
```

See [Entity Framework Cache Busting](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/) for more information on how to disable cache with Entity Framework

With Entity Framework Core, you can also change this settings at [the context level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) :

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourContext.Entry(yourEntity).Reload();
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24522616/4573839).