# Use Single SqlConnection object throughout request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I use actions and child actions in my MVC4 project. İn a view I call nearly ten child actions and each child action opens and closes SqlConnection for itself. Each connection login consumes processor. How can I use a single SqlConnection object for all child actions?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the ADO .NET Connection P- oh wait, you already are.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334592/one-dbcontext-per-request-in-asp-net-mvc-without-ioc-container/10153406#10153406

Comment: @walther, this ooks like a write answer. Thanks.

Comment: @walther, while analyzing with sql profiler, it seams that it logouts per two or three queries. However I keep it opened. At Application_EndRequest I close it.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly: what is your concern here? Since `SqlConnection` uses connection pooling by default, this won't usually have any significant overhead - it isn't spinning up *actual* connections each time.

But: to fix this you could consider storing the connection in the request context; you would also need to add some code to fire at the end of the request to clean up (dispose) the connection.

Comment: +1 But I think storing it inside the request context is a missed opportunity to instead use some IoC container with per-request lifecycle management.