# asp mvc 5 entity framework Related items sometimes disappear

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I m working on MVC5 project and there's problem with related items when retrieved.

1st I've some models like:
Menu, MenuContents one-to-many related, menu has many `menuContents` with different languages

```
public class Menu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MenuContent> MenuContents {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class MenuContent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

But when I using menu object's `menuContents` there's sometimes no items or sometimes not all items there.

To describe well: There's 2 contents for 1 menu. Sometimes there's only 1 item in menu's `menuContents` property but sometimes it's zero or maybe 2.

Wondering what's wrong here. Furthermore missing items are so few only sometimes appears. Why are only some appearing?

Comment: Plus: I m using Data Annotations.

Comment: Do you mean the objects are not correctly populated? Or that they are not showing in a view? And what Data Annotations (there are none shown in your code)? You need to explain whats happening and include the relevant code.

Comment: Added formatting, clarified question.

Comment: Not correctly populated. Above I added only property without annotations.
`[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Menu")]
public virtual List<MenuContent> MenuContents { get; set; }`

`[ForeignKey("MenuID")]
public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't using one context per request. Which means I was using new `DBContext` in every controller.

When I used 1 `DBContext` per request my problem solved /thanks for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334592/one-dbcontext-per-request-in-asp-net-mvc-without-ioc-container) post/.

Hope this helps someone later.