# How to use one database context for all instances that make use of a repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I have made some architectural MVC-mistake since I did not know of the

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

error.

My setup is as follows: I have a `repository` for accessing the database which creates an instance of `dbcontext`, I have controllers that instantiate `managers` they need, the `managers` all instantiate their own `repository`. Here is the problem, when a controllers uses more than one `manager` to collect data and then try to create an object that uses this data, the error above appears when adding the object to the `dbcontext`.

I read about the UnitOfWork pattern, but it seems like a lot of work to restructure my code around that. Is there a quick fix to be able to update the database and avoid the error?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice if you can include some code sample demonstrating your set up. Just include relevant code. BTW how does your managers instantiate dbContext, in using(){} construct?

Comment: To use one database context across your managers and repositories, you could pass it in when you instantiate them e.g. via the constructor

Comment: You can add some dependency injection mechanism, and create one `DbContext` per request. Then in repositories just get `DbContext` instance from IoC container, rather that create new one every time. With this approach you will not need to rewrite your repositories very much.

Comment: @sbirthare I will update the question this evening and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @sbirthare, the repository instantiates a dBcontext and every manager has its own repository. There is no using block, the context is instantiated in the repository's constructor.

Comment: @aleksandrivanov Thanks. I will try using a IoC container or other solution for storing the context per request like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334592/one-dbcontext-per-request-in-asp-net-mvc-without-ioc-container. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one of the ways to fix your problem in quick way will be to add dependency injection. Of course in ideal world repositories should have only `DbContext` instance and do not know nothing about how it was created.

You have not provided any code samples so I will present very simple examples.

In this example [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) is used as IoC container. Write this code in `Global.asax.Application_Start` method.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<YourDbContext>().As<IYourDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

And then in your repository:

```
public class Repository1
{
    public IYourDbContext DbContext { get; private set; }

    public Repository1()
    {
        // How it's probably have been before
        // DbContext = new YourDbContext();

        // Getting DbContext from IoC container
        DbContext = (IYourDbContext) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IYourDbContext));
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add extra libraries, you could save `DbContext` instance at `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like what I need. I am running on Mono an autofac seems I have some difficulties with that judging from a search but I will find a way. Why IDbcontext?

Comment: My bad, there is no such thing like `IDbContext`, I changed that in my answer. But it is always a good idea to have interface property for objects like `DbContext`, like in my example `IYourDbContext`. This approach will simplify future changes and makes code much easier to test.

Comment: How do I dispose the DbContext?

Comment: The `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` always returns null. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Alright, using the concrete implementation instead of the interface (i.e. `builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();`) works, but I still get the error `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.`.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html) and check if your autofac configuration is correct. These 2 lines are important: `var container = builder.Build();     DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));`. And you don't need to worry about disposing objects, autofac will do it for you automatically.

Comment: Also note, that I changed `InstancePerHttpRequest` (which is used for Web API) to `InstancePerRequest`. Sorry for confusion. If you will not use interface you don't need to use `As<>`, just leave it to be `builder.RegisterType<YourDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();`.