# How to use constructor with parameters from one without parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, constructor, dependency-injection

I have a controller which takes a `DbContext` and one who does not. I.e.,:

```
public CalendarController()
{
    var db = new DbContext(); 
    CalendarController(db); // <= Not allowed
}

public CalendarController(IDbContext db)
{
    _calendarManager = new CalendarManager(db);
    _userManager = new UserManager(db);
    _farmingActionManager = new FarmingActionManager(db);
    _cropManager = new CropManager(db);
}
```

Unfortunately the above gives an error on the `CalendarController(db)` line:

> Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'method group` was expected

Is it possible to call one constructor from another? I don't want to duplicate all the code.

Comment: Apparently you're trying to implement Bastard injection anti-pattern. No! don't do that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Could you explain what Bastard Injection Anti-Pattern is? I am doing it in this way since I need the same instance of DbContext per controller instance, I haven't found a better solution. `autofac` was promising, but it still gave the error of using multiple DbContext instances in one request.

Comment: You're not understanding the DI fully. when you use `new` keyword except in composition root(value objects are exception), then you're violating DI. You're newing up `CalendarManager`, `UserManager` etc, which you should be really taking them as a constructor parameter(as some interface). That said, Bastard Injection is something which occurs when a dependency is Foreign Default(implemented in different assembly) which was injected by default. `DbContext` is a foreign dependency(I believe); you shouldn't be tightly couple the consumer with dependency in another assembly.

Comment: If you really want to become good in dependency injection, I recommend [Mark Seemann's book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1935182501/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1935182501&linkCode=as2&tag=ploeh-20). In fact, I'm reading it right now :)

Comment: Look, I had them as constructor parameters at first, but then when doing updates to the database I got the error `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker` (see [this SO-question I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221881/how-to-use-one-database-context-for-all-instances-that-make-use-of-a-repository)). All managers need the same `DbContext` instance per constructor. How would I accomplish that with injecting all the managers? Where is the starting point?

Comment: I see the answer in your previous question uses [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). It is partially correct; You shouldn't use that either. As a starting point a [sample is here](http://pastebin.com/yg5R1CXZ). You should have got the idea from it. If your concern is Conroller class should have default constructor, then no you can implement [custom controller factory](http://develoq.net/2010/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc/). I hope this helps. I'm happy to provide more information.

Comment: Please note that having multiple constructors on your services (such as controllers) [is an anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks for the recommendation. I am reading the Mark Seeman book now (a colleague adviced it as well) and see how things could be improved. Now I am using Autofac as a DI-container and inject all managers in the constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to chain to the constructor like this:

```
public CalendarController() : this(new DbContext())
{
}
```

That's the syntax for chaining to *any* constructor in the same class - it doesn't have to be from a parameterless one to a parameterized one, although it does have to be to a different one :)

Note that this comes before the body of the constructor, so you can't do anything else first, although you *can* call static methods to compute arguments to the other constructor. You can't use *instance* methods or properties though. So this is okay:

```
public Foo() : this(GetDefaultBar())
{
}

public Foo(int bar) { ... }

private static int GetDefaultBar() { ... }
```

But this isn't:

```
public Foo() : this(GetDefaultBar())
{
}

public Foo(int bar) { ... }

private int GetDefaultBar() { ... }
```

The syntax to chain to a constructor in the base class is similar:

```
public Foo() : base(...)
```

If you don't specify either `: base(...)` or `: this(...)` the compiler implicitly adds a `: base()` for you. (That doesn't necessarily chain to a parameterless constructor; it could have optional parameters.)

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Jon's answer is full of good information. Good to know. But, since you've tagged the question with dependency injection, I recommend not to do fall in Bastard Injection. Consider my comments just below your post.