# How can I close connection string object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Today I got an exception when I run my application from the below code

```
dbContext.ManageTasks.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
```

Error is

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I got a solution from this discussion : [How can I solve a connection pool problem between ASP.NET and SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server)

**Solution is** : if I close current connection string object, then this error will be gone.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
myConnection.Open();
// some code
myConnection.Close();
```

The above code for ADO.NET, not Entity Framework.

How can I close the connection string object in Entity Framework?

Comment: with a 'using' block https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Comment: You are not "closing the connection string". You are closing the connection to the database. At least that's what you should be doing.

Comment: XY problem. OP has mistakenly used a long-lived global data context instead of using many short-lived contexts. Don't fix this specific problem. You need to change your architecture so that the context is not a long-lived global.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888185/entity-framework-context-as-static

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure as to why you would need the use of "SqlConnection". DbContext is a disposable class. I found the safest way to clean up is by using the "using" tag. E.g.

```
using(DbContext _context = new MyContext())
{
     \\Your Work here
}
```

This will automatically call _context.Dispose() when it reaches the closing curly bracket which in effect closes your connection.

The alternative would be:

```
DbContext _context = new MyContext();
_context.ManageTasks.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
_context.Dispose();
```

This does mean it's possible to miss the dispose call if an exception occurs.

Hope this helps.

### Useful Link

In order to handle transaction scope and to help dispose your objects, you may want to look at the repository pattern and the unitOfWork pattern. Or [both](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Further to this, I know use DependencyInjection to handle a lot of connections. I just ensure they are Scoped (per web request) :)

Comment: You are missing the `try ... finally` part of `using`.

Comment: it's not good for me, because i have created the object globally for context class `TimeSheetEntity dbContext = new TimeSheetEntity()`

Comment: A "try" is not linked in any way to the using statement, granted it can be used but that's a developer decision based on what code is being run inside the using statement.

Comment: Ramesh, use the alternative. You can call .Dispose() at any time you like. Then I would re-instantiate dbContext in the constructor.

Comment: @RameshRajendran That's your mistake. **The context class should not be long-lived**. You need to redesign your app so that the context is non-global. Create a context per logical database operation. **Don't use a global context**.

Comment: The alternative option is better for me.

Comment: But i can't  do it non globally. because i need to create new object to separate methods. So it will go to broke some performance. So i can't do that.

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes you can. The other option is to carry on with a design that doesn't work. That would be stupid.

Comment: Agree with @spender a lot. You shouldn't make it global as in my answer. If you use the alternative, make sure to use a `try ... finally` block.

Comment: Oh definitely, the using statement is by far the preferred solution. In fact I actually use the UnitOfWork Pattern: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 4):

You are probably keeping a global variable `dbContext` somewhere in your class. You should not do that!

You could use the `IDisposable` interface that `DbContext` implements and use `using` statements. You initialize a new `DbContext` whenever you need one:

```
using (YourDbContext dbContext = ...)
{
    // do some actions
}

// context will be closed
```

The benefit of using `using` is that it will close and dispose, even if the code inside will throw an exception.