# concurrent accesses on EntityFramework 5.0 on insert

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, entity-framework-5

I'm facing some issue with Entity Framework 5.0.

I have a WCF SOAP webservice with a method that create 2 entities in two mysql tables.

Entity B contains further informations to Entity A : so Entity A Primary Key is the same as Entity B PrimaryKey (like a Foreign Key).

[image]

When I create the whole entity (A+B), I don't have PK from Entity A used for entity B. So I need to save on context Entity A, then Entity B, then savechanges to commit.

```
    taskDao.Save(task);
    taskRenderingDao.Save(taskRendering);
    taskDao.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is, when I have concurrent accesses, It happens that context is a bad state, and it returns me the following error : "unique constraint violating on PK".

Someone can help me to solve it ?

Thank you
Guillaume.

Comment: Please post your two tables or poco classes.

Comment: You need to create new db context per SOAP request, or introduce locking mechanism

Comment: @DarjanBogdan locking mechanish as I do for a threading method ?

Comment: @RicardoSerra I've just did it

Comment: @GuillaumeP. yes because that's actually happening on your WCF service, server creates  2 threads (for 2 SOAP requests) which work concurrently on the **same** EF (db) context.

Comment: "The problem is, when I have concurrent accesses, It happens that context is a bad state" - if you never use same context from multiple threads - it won't be in bad state. So just don't ever use same context from multiple threads (and better not reuse context at all).

Comment: @RicardoSerra thank you for your help

Comment: @Evk thank you for your help too

Comment: If you are reusing your context object, you're going to have a very bad time...

Comment: @RicardoSerra I used static context for this app, so I assume it is a bad way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, that's a really bad idea. Always create a new context object, never reuse it.

Comment: @DavidG yes I see it. I will try to use a locking mechanism. Do you prefer a new one maybe ?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I tried to lock access to insert method used by EF 5 but it doesn't work. May you help me?

Comment: @GuillaumeP. I strongly suggest you not to use static EF context, please read more about the [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888185/entity-framework-context-as-static). However if you want to proceed with locking, please post your solution so I can help you properly.

Comment: @DarjanBogdan It's ok, the only way I solve it is by using a new context as you tell me. But locking mechanism didn't work maybe because I failed it. Thank you for you help (y)